# Delete lfs files from GitHub repo

Tags: git, github, git-lfs, git-fork, git-refspec

I have a github repo with around 1.7GB of lfs storage used for which I am paying the upgraded storage plan.

Me and my group of 6 other people used this repo during a university games project, they all made forks of it and made pull requests into the main (my) repo. Now that it is no longer needed I would like to move the files off of git-lfs so that I can downgrade my GitHub storage plan.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57681990/15995062) already which works upto the point of pushing the re-written git history to the remote. It gives the following error

Could this be down to the fact everyone has forks of this project which is somehow interfering with the hooks

```
$ git push -f origin main
Counting objects: 29565, done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (15821/15821), done.
Writing objects: 100% (29565/29565), 1.14 GiB | 5.88 MiB/s, done.
Total 29565 (delta 20562), reused 19031 (delta 13663)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (20562/20562), done.
remote: warning: File Freight/Assets/Audio/backGroundMusic.mp3 is 55.00 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: warning: File Freight/Library/ArtifactDB is 64.00 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: c9bef6e7c4f23ee4f0736658211f57157ea734dda69a25e5edc662c1b2cf04a4
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File frontend/public/Build/webstef4.data.unityweb is 113.81 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File frontend/public/Build/webstef4.data.unityweb is 107.64 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To git@github.com:user/repo.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:user/repo.git'
```

(side note, I also deleted the frontend folder, but it is still trying to push it even though it doesn't exist I assume this is because the file was added at some point in the git history and therefore the file is still present but hidden)

Comment: If you've already run `git lfs migrate`, I'd suggest contacting GitHub support directly at this point.