# Remove Git LFS with filter-branch? (Can't re-add unchanged file to index.)

Tags: git, github, git-lfs, git-filter-branch, git-lfs-migrate

Trying to migrate a repo (including history) OUT of Git LFS.

I ran `git lfs migrate export --include="*" --everything` (mentioned [here](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/man/git-lfs-migrate.1.ronn)) on a test repo, but it didn't work as expected and left LFS pointer files instead of converting them all to objects.

I tried alternative methods, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699293/how-to-i-disable-git-lfs). Unfortunately it still left pointer files, so I combined it with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35011366/move-git-lfs-tracked-files-under-regular-git).

In the end, I even ran all the commands together:

```
git lfs uninstall
git filter-branch -f --prune-empty --tree-filter '
  git lfs fetch
  git lfs checkout
  git lfs ls-files | cut -d " " -f 3 | xargs touch
  git lfs ls-files | cut -d " " -f 3 | xargs git rm --cached
  git rm -f .gitattributes
  git lfs ls-files | cut -d " " -f 3 | xargs git add --force
  git add --renormalize .
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Didn't work. Gave me the following error for multiple files, and the filtered commits have pointer files instead of the objects.

```
Errors logged to <PATH>
Use `git lfs logs last` to view the log.
Rewrite <COMMIT SHA ####> (2/9) (2 seconds passed, remaining 7 predicted)    
Checking out LFS objects:   0% (0/1), 0 B | 0 B/s           
Checking out LFS objects: 100% (2/2), 3.1 KB | 0 B/s, done
Error updating the git index:
error: picture.png: cannot add to the index - missing --add option?
fatal: Unable to process path picture.png
```

I tried running the same commands on only the tip commit, and it seems like `touch`, `rm --cached`, `add --renormalize .`, `add --force` don't show any modifications with `git status`. So I'm unable to re-add the cleaned/pulled object files to a new commit.

Maybe that's the problem? So how to forcibly re-add unchanged file to index when using filter-branch?

(Using Windows with git bash.)

Comment: Did you tried `git lfs migrate export`? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57681990/717372

Comment: @Philippe That was the first thing I tried. Didn't work somehow... left pointer files in my history, and wiped the LFS objects folder too :(

Comment: @Philippe I reread the post and noticed I set my --include option differently. After following the steps exactly, the content files successfully replaced the pointers. But it gives me a new problem! Checkout of any commit shows the error "Encountered # file(s) that should have been pointers, but weren't", and files appear as modified so git forces me to add them to a new commit.

Comment: I imagine that you got this message because you still have got lfs installed (you have to remove the filters in the `.gitattributes` file)

Comment: @Philippe You're right. Afterwards, I did a dummy commit followed by a tree-filter with ```git rm -f .gitattributes```. Worked out nicely. (This surprises me because ```git lfs migrate export``` already added a line to ```.gitattributes``` to negate the lfs filters, but maybe I specified the files incorrectly.) Thanks! If you want to add your answer, I'll accept it (or I can add it). :)

Comment: I wrote a slightly better answer ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Do a `git lfs migrate export --everything --include .` to replace all the LFS pointers by the real files in the git history. For more details, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/57681990/717372
2. Run `git lfs uninstall` to remove lfs hooks.
3. And verify that the `.gitattributes` has the lfs filters removed.

   If the lfs filters were not removed, and if `.gitattributes` was only needed for LFS, delete the file in all of history with:

   ```
   git filter-branch -f --prune-empty --tree-filter '
     git rm -f .gitattributes --ignore-unmatch
   ' --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
   ```

   Otherwise if `.gitattributes` has non-LFS lines, remove only the LFS filters by replacing the above tree-filter command with `git lfs untrack` (reference [here](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/man/git-lfs-untrack.1.ronn) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35011366/move-git-lfs-tracked-files-under-regular-git)).