# LFS Object stuck in Git history

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push, git-lfs

I am building a static website and tried to upload a large video file thanks to Git LFS, but the commit/push never succeeded. After some change I decided to not upload this file and wanted to uninstall LFS. Now the object keeps uploading every-time I try to push on Github and I can not push any update. When I type "git push origin main", the LFS object uploading starts. It looks like it is stuck in the Git History. I tried to delete the repo, create a new one and push again, but same problem.

Any idea on the process to fix this issue ?

Thanks a lot for your help,

I'm available if you need more details

Comment: Did you enable git LFS on the repository archive? You should check "Include Git LFS objects in archives "

Answer (score 0):

If, by pushing the same repository, the issue persists, check locally the content of that repository.

In particular, from "[Simple steps to uninstall Git LFS from your repository](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/3026)", look for any `.gitattributes` file which would still have any LFS-related entry.

See also "[Move Git LFS tracked files under regular Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54119191/6309)"

```sh
git lfs untrack '<pattern>'
git add --renormalize .
git commit -m 'Restore file contents that were previously in LFS'
```

---

The [OP hbonnaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16059174/hbonnaf) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70839560/lfs-object-stuck-in-git-history/70845191#comment125251931_70845191):

> I just used a radical solution that worked:
>
> I fetched an old version of my code from my remote repo. T

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I updated my answer above as this solution didnt work..

Comment: Okay - I just used a radical solution that worked, I fetched an old version of my code from my remote repo. 

Thanks for your help, really appreciated

Comment: @hbonnaf OK. I have edited the answer to include your comment for more visibility.